# circular(ish) motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, kinematics

how would one describe as a function of time the position vector of an object with initial position $\vec{x_0}$ and velocity $\vec{ v_0}$ experiencing a central force of constant magnitude around the origin.

The closest thing I have done to this is circular motion, however, all of it descriptions are based on the constraint that the object is moving in a circle, which would not, at least initially, be the case here.

Comment: What is "centripetal force" supposed to mean if the object is not moving in a circle?

Comment: the direction is always directed to the center as defined

Comment: If you just mean a force directed towards a fixed center, then that's a ["central" force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_central-force_problem), not a centripetal force.

Comment: I see, thank you for that correction.

Comment: the question has been changed

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is the following: take the velocity $\vec{v}_{\mathrm{circ}}$ that is equal to the velocity that the object would have if it were in uniform circular motion with the given force and its current position were $\vec{x}_0$.

Rewrite the velocity $\vec{v}_0$ as

$$\vec{v}_0 = (\vec{v}_0 - \vec{v}_{\mathrm{circ}}) + \vec{v}_{\mathrm{circ}}. $$

The motion of the object is then the circular motion associated with $\vec{v}_{\mathrm{circ}}$ and the given force plus the uniform straight motion $(\vec{v}_0 - \vec{v}_{\mathrm{circ}})\,t$.

To convince yourself that this works, substitute $\vec{x}'(t) = \vec{x}(t) + \vec{v}'\,t$ in the equation of motion, assuming that $\vec{x}(t)$ is a known solution of the equation.